# Django auth_user and custom user confusion

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I am trying to implement a application where the `clients` can sign up and use our services. One `clients` can creates many `users` and define the `roles`. There can be multiple clients which will have their specific users. For the model what I have in mind is:

```
class Client(models.Model):
     # Client attributes

class ClientUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    # Other attributes
```

Is this the correct way to define model in this scenario? Because default `User` model in Django already have the `is_superuser` attribute. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you allowing them in admin portal? If so, create a custom page for that.

Comment: I am not sure about that. Probably, I will make a pass on django admin interface and may be build my own because there would be multiple site settings I don't want to show those clients?

Comment: Also, it is going to be public application so I think it would be better to not use the `admin` app.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of customizing your user model: via a one-to-one relation, or extending the User model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model